# Getting to the bottom and saving a webpage which has "Infinite scrolling"

Tags: tumblr

There is a Tumblr blog which is just one long page with thousands of entries. Once I reach what appears to be the bottom of the page, more text/posts loads.

How I get to the bottom of the page without scrolling/pressing page down? Is there some way of doing this? I don't mind using Firefox, Chrome or Edge.

My aim is to save the page on my HD, so that I can read it from chronological order (unfortunately, the archive feature of Tumblr doesn't work on this blog).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way. It involves opening the developer console of your browser. That is done usually by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or just <kbd>F12</kbd>.

After you've opened it and found the **Console** tab, type:

```
var i = 0;
(function scroll () {
  if (i > 50) {
    return
  }
  i++
  window.scrollTo(0, 9999999)
  console.log('scrolled ' + i)
  setTimeout(scroll, 900)
})()
```

Then watch as it scrolls 50 times with an interval of 900 milliseconds between each forced scroll. That should be enough for many cases.

Answer (score -2):

I am not aware of a command or keystroke that can load an infinite scroll page automatically and take you to the bottom. However, I have seen Chrome extensions that claim to do this for you.

Comment: Please provide an actual answer, this type of response is usually reserved for comments.